# white-space: pre-line; doesn't work on MS Edge print mode

Tags: css, printing, microsoft-edge

https://jsfiddle.net/rsa4o2qp/

```css
p {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<p>
              line 1
              
              line 2
              
              line 3
</p>
```

When the above example is opened in Edge 17, it is rendered correctly, like this:

```
line 1

line 2

line 3
```

However, when you try to print it from this browser, it gets messed up. The print preview displays it as:

```
line 1 line 2
line 3
```

Is that a browser's bug or my fault?

Answer (score 1):

@prichna

if you use  **white-space: pre;** instead of white-space: pre-line its work perfectly in print also from edge browser.

Comment: `white-space: pre;` does not format the `<p>` element as I want. It leaves whitespace at the beginning of lines.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested out the snippet you have created. Although Edge itself renders the CSS property correctly, there seems to be a problem with Edge's Print Preview. As Edge is still not a mature Web Browser these kind of issues/bugs are expected. You can open a new issue at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/ or you can use twitter too to open bugs on Edge - Just use #EdgeBug tag and describe your bug.